# How to save records into master detail table in VB.NET?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have two tables named **tbParent(cid, Class)** and **tbChild (id, cid, Section)**  with Master Detail relation

cid is primary key for **tbParent** and foreign key for **tbChild**

I have to use one form to save record into both tables

Example:

```
         cid class
         ----  ----
          1    Ten
          

          id cid Sec
          --- --- ---
           1  1   A
           2  1   B
           3  1   C
```

How can I save using code inside vb.net? My database is MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified so I'm going to assume that the PK columns are type `AutoNumber`. That is relevant information that you should always provide. In that case, you need to retrieve the autogenerated ID from the database after inserting the parent record. The global variable `@@IDENTITY` always contains the last autogenerated ID, so you can get it from there. Here's an example that uses `ExecuteNonQuery` to insert records one by one:

```vb
Using connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here")
    connection.Open()

    Dim parentInsertCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Parent (ParentName) VALUES (@ParentName)", connection)

    parentInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParentName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = parentName
    parentInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim parentIdSelectCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", connection)
    Dim parentId = CInt(parentIdSelectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
    Dim childInsertCommand As New OleDbCommand("INERT INTO Child (ChildName, ParentId) VALUES (@ChildName, @ParentId)", connection)
    Dim childNameParameter = childInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ChilName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)

    childInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParentId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = parentId

    For Each childName In childNames
        childNameParameter.Value = childName
        childInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Using
```

Alternatively, you can use a `DataSet` to store all the data with a `DataRelation` between `DataTables` and then save data with data adapters. You can use the events of the `DataTable` to retrieve the autogenerated IDs. I won't provide a full example of that unless it's specifically what you need but [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052)'s one I prepared earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I use to save to TWO Tables Look at the TEST If at the bottom of the Insert Into Child It is a SQLite Embedded DB concept the same for Access

```
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    If Len(tbTitle.Text.Trim) = 0 Then
        tbMessage.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        tbMessage.Text = "Enter the Title"
        tbTitle.Select()
        Return
    End If
    If rtbEnter.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
        tbMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red
        tbMessage.Text = "Enter Data to SAVE"
        rtbEnter.Select()
        Return
    End If

    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
    Dim dbName As String = "Notes.db"
    Dim conn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source =" & dbName & ";Version=3;")

    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ChildTable (cDispDate,cMonth,cYear,cTitle,cEntry) VALUES (@cDispDate,@cMonth,@cYear,@cTitle,@cEntry)"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDispDate", tbDispDate.Text.Trim)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cMonth", tbMonth.Text.Trim)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cYear", tbYear.Text.Trim)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cTitle", tbTitle.Text.Trim)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cEntry", rtbEnter.Text.Trim)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

        If colMonth = tbMonth.Text Then
            frmStart.tbMessage.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            frmStart.tbMessage.Text = "Record Added"
            'btnBack_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
            tbMessage.Text = "Click Back to Finish"
        Else
            InsertInToParent()
        End If
        'Notice Code Above it only saves to parent if it is a new Month
        '==============================================================
    Catch ex As Exception
        tbMessage.Text = "Child Table Failed"
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub InsertInToParent()

    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
    Dim dbName As String = "Notes.db"
    Dim conn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source =" & dbName & ";Version=3;")

    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ParentTable (pMonth,pYear) VALUES (@pMonth,@pYear)"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pMonth", tbMonth.Text.Trim)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pYear", tbYear.Text.Trim)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", CInt(TextBox3.Text))

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

        frmStart.tbMessage.ForeColor = Color.Black
        frmStart.tbMessage.Text = "Record Added"
        btnSave.Enabled = False

    Catch ex As Exception
        tbMessage.Text = "Parent Table Failed"
    End Try

End Sub
```